# C++: Vector element assignment causing Access violation

Tags: c++, vector, c++14, access-violation

When breaking up a string within C++ into individual lines and parameters (as a 2D vector) it can create the interesting problem of access violations when attempting to parse the vectors between functions.
Within the code example, there have been many attempts to ensure that data is passed to and from the functions are independent objects and in no way a reference.

*segregate.hpp*

```
#pragma once

#include <vector>
#include <string>

/*
  Purpose:
    To to take a whole file as a string,
    and break it up into individual words
*/

namespace Segregate {
  // Module types
  typedef std::vector< std::string > ParamArray;
  struct StrCommand{
    unsigned long line;
    ParamArray param;
  };
  typedef std::vector< StrCommand > StrCommands;

  bool IsParamBreak(char val);
  bool IsLineBreak(char val);

  ParamArray Parameterize(std::string str);
  StrCommands Fragment(std::string str);
}


#include "./segregate.cpp"
```

*segregate.cpp*

```
#include "./segregate.hpp"

namespace Segregate{
    bool IsParamBreak(char val){
        if (val == ' '){
            return true;
        }else if (val == '\t'){
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    };
    bool IsLineBreak(char val){
        if (val == '\n'){
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    };

    // Splits a single line into individual parameters
    ParamArray Parameterize(std::string str){
        str.append(" "); // Ensures that the loop will cover all segments
        unsigned long length = str.size();
        unsigned long comStart = 0;
        ParamArray res;


        // Ignore carrage returns
        //  Windows artifact
        if (str[0] == '\r'){
            comStart = 1;
        }


        // Ignore indentation
        //  Find the start of actual content
        while (comStart < length && IsParamBreak(str[comStart])){
            comStart++;
        }

        // Count the number of parameters
        unsigned long vecLen = 0;
        for (unsigned long i=comStart; i<length; i++){
            if ( IsParamBreak(str[i]) ){
                vecLen++;
            }
        }
        res.reserve(vecLen);


        // Scan will fail if there is no data
        if (length == 0){
            return res;
        }


        // Slice the the string into parts
        unsigned long toIndex = 0;
        unsigned long cursor = comStart;
        for (unsigned long i=cursor; i<length; i++){
            if (IsParamBreak(str[i]) == true){
                // Transfer the sub-string to the vector,
                //  Ensure that the data is it's own, and not a reference
                res[toIndex].reserve(i-cursor);

                // Error here
                res[toIndex].assign( str.substr(cursor, i-cursor) );

                cursor = i+1;
                toIndex++;
            }
        }

        return res;
    };


    StrCommands Fragment(std::string str){
        str.append("\n"); // Ensures that the loop will cover all segments
        unsigned long length = str.size();

        // Result
        StrCommands res;


        // Count lines
        //  Ignoring empty lines
        unsigned long vecLen = 1;
        for (unsigned long i=0; i<length; i++){
            if (IsLineBreak(str[i])){
                vecLen++;
            }
        }
        res.reserve(vecLen);


        // Ignore 'empty' strings as they may cause errors
        if (vecLen == 0){
            return res;
        }


        // Read lines
        unsigned long toIndex = 0;
        unsigned long cursor = 0;
        for (unsigned long i=0; i<length; i++){
            if (IsLineBreak(str[i])){

                // Error here
                res[toIndex].param = ParamArray(  Parameterize( std::string(str.substr(cursor, i-cursor)) )  );
                res[toIndex].line = i+1;

                // Ignore blank lines
                if (res[toIndex].param.size() == 0){
                    vecLen--;
                }else{
                    toIndex++;
                }
                cursor = i+1;
            }
        }


        // Shrink the result due to undersizing for blank lines
        res.reserve(vecLen);

        return res;
    };
}
```

Memory access violations normally occur on lines 66 & 108 (when the element data is stored locally within a vector). It appears to occur during the assignment phase, as deduced by using an intermidiate temporary variable to store the result directly after it's parsing.
The error can also occur during vector::reserve(), tho that occurs less often.

---

**Note:** On Windows there is no direct error message:

> Exception thrown at 0x00A20462 in fiber.exe: 0xC0000005: Access
>   violation reading location 0xBAADF009.

is only seen when using 'C/C++ Extension for Visual Studio Code' debugging, not within normal terminal execution.
However on Ubuntu it outputs:

> Segmenation fault (core dump)

Comment: Use `std::vector::resize` instead of `std::vector::reserve`.

Comment: Edit your question to include a [mcve].

Comment: *Memory access violations normally occur on lines 66 & 108* -- ok, let me count.  1, 2, 3, 4,...forget it.  What line is 66 and what line is 108?

Comment: Also, if your goal is to break up a file into individual words, you could have used `std::istringstream` to do that job instead of writing all of that code.

Comment: You are using reserve() which allocates the memory but doesn't construct any objects so on line 72 you allocate memory but the size() of the vector is still 0 and then on line 88 you try to use the vector at index 0 which doesn't exist because the size of res is still 0.

Comment: [Is this basically what you are trying to do?](https://www.ideone.com/a4hriJ)

Comment: `#include "./segregate.cpp"` is something you should not do. When you `#include`, you effectively replace the line with with a pasted-in copy of the included file. This often leads to problems linking later when the linker finds copies of segregate.cpp all over the place and can't figure out which is real.

Comment: @user4581301 within the first line of segregate.hpp I have the precompiler command "#pragma once", thus the .cpp content will only be included once, as long as all references to 'segregate' are to the .hpp

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie you could copy it to an IDE if you had the time, but I also reference what happens at those lines, and include comments to point out those lines "// Error"

Comment: @JerryJeremiah now that you point it out it seems obvious that the vectors would not be initialized, thus they would have invalid default data, thus if you try to use them, it could/can write out of domain/access.
Also, I feel weird using vector::resize due to their wording "If n is greater than the current container size, the content is expanded by inserting at the end as many elements as needed to reach a size of n", which seems to imply that it will just expand the object, possibly writing over any data after it.

Comment: You slightly misinterpret what `once` does. It guarantees only one inclusion per translation unit (one compiled source file). If you are compiling multiple source files, all bets are off. Each translation unit can include the file once, resulting in chaos when the linker assembles the translation units into a single program.

Comment: `vector` contains a pointer to a dynamically allocated block somewhere in memory. `resize` will either expand over any unused capacity in the `vector`'s storage block (no worries about overwriting valid data, there is nothing there) or if the new size is greater than the capacity, `vector` will allocate a new block at least large enough to store the requested number of elements and copy over the data from the old block and fill up the unused before freeing the old block. No data is overwritten and lost unless you have a bug that's been writing to memory it shouldn't have been.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are calling `reserve` on your vector which allocates memory to store your objects but doesn't construct them. When you then try and use the methods of the objects which you haven't constructed it's likely to crash.

There are 2 possible solutions, either call `resize` instead of `reserve` or call `push_back` to construct new objects at the end of the vector.